# CLLocationManager - Coordinates to Address

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm using a CLLocationManager in an attempt to find the address that the user is currently at.  How can I convert the coordinates returned by the class to an actual address/business without a visual map view? Or is there a different class to return this data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323) class:

> The MKReverseGeocoder class provides services for converting a map
>   coordinate (specified as a latitude/longitude pair) into information
>   about that coordinate, such as the country, city, or street. A reverse
>   geocoder object is a single-shot object that works with a
>   network-based map service to look up placemark information for its
>   specified coordinate value.

However, you mention you do not want to provide a map. This violates [the terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html):

> The MapKit framework uses Google services to provide map data. (...)
>   The Google terms of service require that the reverse geocoding service
>   be used in conjunction with a Google map; take this into account when
>   designing your application's user interface.

If you definetely do not want to prove a map, you may have to look into a reverse geocoding service other than Google's.